# How do I create a mapped type from the keys of a fixed object in Typescript

Tags: typescript, types, mapped-types

I have an object like this:

```
const routes = {
  home: { path: '/', page: 'home' },
  profile: { path: '/profile', page: 'users/profile' }
}
```

I would like to define a derived type from this, like so:

`type RouteName = keyof typeof routes`, which creates a type like `"home" | "profile"`.

However, I can't then do:

```
for (let name in routes) {
  router.add({ name, ...routes[name]})
}
```

because the compiler complains about `routes[name]` being of implicit type `any`:

```
Element implicitly has an 'any' type because type '{ home: { path: string; page: string; }; profile: { path: string; page: string; };' has no index signature.
```

If I modify the definition of routes to:

```
interface RouteDefinition {
  path: string
  page: string
}
const routes: {[key: string]: RouteDefinition} = {
  home: { path: '/', page: 'home' },
  profile: { path: '/profile', page: 'users/profile' }
}
```

the generated type `type RouteName = keyof typeof routes` is now `string` instead of `"home"|"profile"`.

I could of course define a hardcoded `RouteName` type, but in case it isn't clear, I'm trying to avoid having to define the route names in two places, especially when the keys of the object strictly define the set of possibilities.

The object only needs to be defined once, and never needs to be reassigned. I've tried a bunch of combinations of `Readonly<>`, casting etc, but can't figure it out. Is there a way to do this?

(I'm using Typescript 2.8.1)

Comment: There is [this issue](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/12314) about the inferred type when using `for/in`. But it doesn't look like they intend to change the current behavior.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

TypeScript doesn't consider it safe to assume that `for..in` keys are exactly the keys defined in the type, because in JavaScript all objects are open.

You can use an assertion to make the compile error go away:

```
for (let name in routes) {
  routes[name as RouteName]; // no error
}
```

Or, what I would do is combine your two approaches. You can define your `routes` as you are doing, extract the keys as a `RouteName`, but also make a `RouteDefinition` and assign your routes to an indexed type (which could be done using an assertion to a new variable, or a function parameter) when you want to map over them:

```
interface RouteDefinition {
    path: string;
    page: string;
}

const routes = {
    home: { path: '/', page: 'home' },
    profile: { path: '/profile', page: 'users/profile' }
}

type RouteName = keyof typeof routes;

mapRoutes(routes);

function mapRoutes(routes: { [key: string]: RouteDefinition }) {
    for (let name in routes) {
        routes[name] // no error
    }
}
```

If your `routes` literal doesn't satisfy the `RouteDefinition` (missing a key, key of wrong type) then you'll get an error at the assignment site, ie `mapRoutes(routes)` above.